# How to modify parent node before it is passed to a resolver?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Suppose we have this GraphQL schema:

```
type Venue implements Node {
  country: Country!
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  nid: String!
  url: String!
}
```

which is supported by this resolver:

```
// @flow

import type {
  VenueRecordType,
  ResolverType,
} from '../types';

const Venue: ResolverType<VenueRecordType> = {
  country: (node, parameters, context) => {
    return context.loaders.CountryByIdLoader.load(node.countryId);
  },
};

export default Venue;
```

I want to be able to modify the parent/ node parameter value before it is used by the resolver fields.

As far as I can tell having read the documentation, the only way to achieve this is by implementing and wrapping every field, e.g.

```
// @flow

import type {
  VenueRecordType,
  ResolverType,
} from '../types';

const createNodeDecorator = (fieldResolver) => {
  const updateNode = (node) => {
    // https://media0.giphy.com/media/12NUbkX6p4xOO4/giphy.gif
    return node;
  };

  return (parent, parameteres, context, info) => {
    return fieldResolver(updateNode(parent), parameteres, context, info);
  };
};

const Venue: ResolverType<VenueRecordType> = {
  country: createNodeDecorator((node, parameters, context) => {
    return context.loaders.CountryByIdLoader.load(node.countryId);
  }),
  id: createNodeDecorator((node) => {
    return node.id;
  }),
  name: createNodeDecorator((node) => {
    return node.name;
  }),
  nid: createNodeDecorator((node) => {
    return node.nid;
  }),
  url: createNodeDecorator((node) => {
    return node.url;
  }),
};

export default Venue;
```

Is there a better way?

Ideally, I would have a `__load` hook that is called before the resolver is used, e.g.

```
const Venue: ResolverType<VenueRecordType> = {
  __load: (parent, parameteres, context, info, next) => {
    next(parent, parameteres, context, info);
  },
  country: (node, parameters, context) => {
    return context.loaders.CountryByIdLoader.load(node.countryId);
  },
};
```

But this (as far as I can tell) does not exist.

How to modify parent node before it is passed to a resolver?

Comment:  for not only providing a minimal, reproducible but managing to work in a meme in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to move the logic for modifying the node up a level. For example, given a Query type like:

```
type Query {
  venues: [Venue!]!
}
```

we can just do the following inside the resolver:

```
const resolvers: {
  Query: {
    venues: async (root, args, context) => {
      const venues = await context.loaders.VenueLoader.load()
      return venues.map(magic)
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but it means you have to duplicate the logic inside any resolver that returns a Venue or List of Venues, which is tedious and error-prone. If you're already using a loader, I would just move this logic *inside the loader itself* and call it a day.

However, we can take this one step further and use a schema directive as well. This would be helpful if, for example, you wanted to reuse the same logic for different types, or for some weird reason, you wanted to modify the parent only on some fields. Here's an example that would let you apply the directive to either a type or individual fields:

```
class MagicDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field
    field.resolve = function (source, args, context, info) {
      return resolve.apply(this, [magic(source), args, context, info])
    }
  }
  visitObject(object) {
    const fieldMap = object.getFields()
    for (const fieldName in fieldMap) {
      this.visitFieldDefinition(fieldMap[fieldName])
    }
  }
}
```

Then just pass the directive in to your `ApolloServer` config as part of `schemaDirectives` and include it in your type definitions:

```
directive @magic on FIELD_DEFINITION | OBJECT
```

Comment: Never took enough time to learn schema directive until after your answer. They are awesome! My use case is to implement a resolver pattern described in this post. https://medium.com/paypal-engineering/graphql-resolvers-best-practices-cd36fdbcef55 Effectively, it is assumed that parent node only returns ID – it is up the resolver objects to fetch their data. As you mentioned, this reduces code duplication in the parent node.

Comment: @Gajus Thanks for sharing that article. That *is* a pretty cool pattern, especially if you're already working with DataLoader. FWIW, I don't think embracing that pattern requires you to explicitly modify your parent values. If you're already getting a "complete" object but only need the id, you don't gain anything from transforming the object except extra overhead.

Comment: @Gajus I've tried that approach, and I think that article is recommending a HUGE antipattern. What happens if the object doesn't exist? You've returned something from your parent, so you're saying that the object exists. The correct response if an object doesn't exist is `null`, and you've now made that impossible.

Comment: How can you return something from the parent if there is nothing to return?

Comment: This is what he recommends: `venueById(parent, args) { return { id: args.id }; }`. He has taken the user's input and returned the object without doing a lookup

Comment: This is just for illustration purposes (I assume). You are expected to lookup the PK value in the parent resolver and then allow children to resolve whatever additional information is needed based on the PK value. The value of this approach is that if you have fairly complicated DataLoader logic, you can keep it in a resolver together with all the other field definitions, and parents no longer need to be aware of the DataLoader pattern.

Comment: @DanCrews Maybe we can [move this conversation to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197310/graphql-resolvers-best-practices)